# How to find the normalisation constant for binomial data?

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to simulate a case control study with some data for $Y=\{0,1\}$. So from

$$ logit P(Y=1)|X=x) = \alpha + x^T\beta_0$$

we get

$$ P(X = x|Y=1) = P(X = x|Y=0)\exp(\alpha^* + x^T\beta_0)$$

where $\alpha^*$ is a normalisation constant.

Now, in my model I have assumed $P(X = x|Y=0) = 1/9$ to be constant as we have discrete $X$. Can I simply estimate $\alpha^*$ to be solved by $\sum 1/9 \exp(\alpha^* + x^T\beta_0)$ = 1 so that  $\alpha^* = log(9) - x^T(s_0)\beta_0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what is $s_0$, but you can simply write

$$\sum \frac{1}{9} \exp(\alpha^\ast + x^T \beta_0) = \frac{\exp(\alpha^\ast)}{9}\sum \exp(x^T\beta_0)=1$$

So that you have

$$\alpha^\ast = \ln 9 - \ln\sum  \exp(x^T\beta_0)$$

As you mentioned $x$ can take only discrete values, knowing them and $\beta_0$ should be enough to know $\alpha^\ast$.

Does that answer your question ?

Comment: Got it, thanks! For the summation of $\exp(x^T\beta_0)$, I have an $9\times 1$ vector, I just sum each of these elements up, right?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes.